# NoSuchMethodError: org.jbehave.core.steps.DelegatingStepMonitor when executing Selenium Jbehave test

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bdd, jbehave

I tried to implement a Selenium + Jbehave solution like this:
https://jbehave.org/reference/web/stable/page-objects.html
but I have some trouble when I trie to execute.

Story runner class:

```
public class TravelLedgerWebStories extends JUnitStories {

private WebDriverProvider driverProvider = new PropertyWebDriverProvider();
private WebDriverSteps lifecycleSteps = new PerStoriesWebDriverSteps(driverProvider);
private Pages pages = new Pages(driverProvider);
private SeleniumContext context = new SeleniumContext();
private ContextView contextView = new LocalFrameContextView().sized(500, 100);

public TravelLedgerWebStories() {
    if ( lifecycleSteps instanceof PerStoriesWebDriverSteps ){
        configuredEmbedder().useExecutorService(new SameThreadExecutors().create(configuredEmbedder().embedderControls()));
    }
}

@Override
public Configuration configuration() {
    Class<? extends Embeddable> embeddableClass = this.getClass();
    return new SeleniumConfiguration()
            .useSeleniumContext(context)
            .useWebDriverProvider(driverProvider)
            .useStepMonitor(new SeleniumStepMonitor(contextView, context, new SilentStepMonitor()))
            .useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(embeddableClass))
            .useStoryReporterBuilder(new StoryReporterBuilder()
                    .withCodeLocation(codeLocationFromClass(embeddableClass))
                    .withDefaultFormats()
                    .withFormats(CONSOLE, TXT, HTML, XML));
}

@Override
public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
    Configuration configuration = configuration();
    return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration,
            new TravelledgerWebSteps(pages),
            lifecycleSteps,
            new WebDriverScreenshotOnFailure(driverProvider, configuration.storyReporterBuilder()));
}


@Override
protected List<String> storyPaths() {
    return new StoryFinder()
            .findPaths(codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()).getFile(), asList("**/*.story"), null);
}
}
```

Step class:

```
public class TravelledgerWebSteps {

private final Pages pages;

public TravelledgerWebSteps(Pages pages) {
    this.pages = pages;
}

@Given("user is on Login page")
public void userIsOnLoginPage(){
    pages.loginPagePOM().open();
}

@Given("I login as: \"$email\" with password: \"$pass\"")
public void loginToMainPage(String email, String pass) {
    pages.transactionsPagePOM().open(email, pass);
}

@Given("Wait for loading main page")
public void waitForMainPage() throws InterruptedException {
    pages.transactionsPagePOM().waitForLoadingMainPage();
}

@Then("Navigate to Import file page")
public void navigateToImportFilePage() {
    pages.transactionsPagePOM().navigateToImportFilePage();
}

@Then("Select Auto commit uploaded invoices checkbox")
public void selectCheckbox() {
    pages.transactionsPagePOM().selectCheckBox();
}

@Then("Upload transaction file")
public void uploadTransactionFile(String location) {
    pages.transactionsPagePOM().uploadTransactionFile(location);
}

@Then("Navigate to Bookings page")
public void navigatesToBookingsPage() {
    pages.transactionsPagePOM().navigatesToBookings();
}

@Then("Check that the transactions have been commited and can be viewed")
public void checkTransactionsCommited() {
    pages.transactionsPagePOM().checkCommitedTransactions();
}

@Then("Logout")
public void logout() {
    pages.transactionsPagePOM().logout();
}
}
```

The Pages object is injected with the Selenium API-specific objects:

```
public class Pages {

private final WebDriverProvider driverProvider;

private LoginPagePOM loginPagePOM;
private TransactionsPagePOM transactionsPagePOM;

public Pages(WebDriverProvider driverProvider) {
    this.driverProvider = driverProvider;
}

public LoginPagePOM loginPagePOM(){
    if ( loginPagePOM == null ){
        loginPagePOM = new LoginPagePOM(driverProvider);
    }
    return loginPagePOM;
}

public TransactionsPagePOM transactionsPagePOM() {
    if ( transactionsPagePOM == null ){
        transactionsPagePOM = new TransactionsPagePOM(driverProvider);
    }
    return transactionsPagePOM;
}}
```

The login Page POM what I want to execute first looks like:

```
public class LoginPagePOM extends AbstractPage{

public LoginPagePOM(WebDriverProvider driverProvider) {
    super(driverProvider);
}

public void open() {
    get("https://qa.abtlg.io");
    manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}}
```

So the pages.loginPagePOM().open() is the enty point.

The error message when I tried to execute TravelledgerWebStories:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jbehave.core.steps.DelegatingStepMonitor.<init>(Lorg/jbehave/core/steps/StepMonitor;)V

at org.jbehave.web.selenium.SeleniumStepMonitor.<init>(SeleniumStepMonitor.java:22)
at travelledgerJbehave.webdriver.TravelLedgerWebStories.configuration(TravelLedgerWebStories.java:43)
at org.jbehave.core.ConfigurableEmbedder.configuredEmbedder(ConfigurableEmbedder.java:122)
at travelledgerJbehave.webdriver.TravelLedgerWebStories.<init>(TravelLedgerWebStories.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:250)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:260)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$2.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)

Process finished with exit code 255
```

I think something in the configuration side go wrong.

I did not setup any driver for example firefox driver like this in my previous project without Jbehave:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/User/Documents/selenium dependencies/drivers/geckodriver");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://qa.abtlg.io");
```

What could be the solution?
Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Do you specify own version of `jbehave-core` dependency somwhere in your project? If you use Maven, could you please post your `pom.xml`?

Comment: I don't use maven, I started a new Java project.
I just add dependencys manually to the External Libraries in IntelliJ.
I see that jbehave-core.jar and jbehave-core-4.8.3.jar are also in the libraries.

Comment: Try to use `jbehave-core:4.1`

Comment: @VaL
Thank you very much, I think I am getting closer to the solution :)
I updated to the jbehave-core-4.8.3.jar and after it a new error message came out that showed the samethreadexecutors class is deprecated.
I changed this class to DirectExecutorService() class, so the stoy executor class constructor is looking like this:

public TravelLedgerWebStories() {
        if ( lifecycleSteps instanceof PerStoriesWebDriverSteps ){
            configuredEmbedder().useExecutorService(new DirectExecutorService().create(configuredEmbedder().embedderControls()));
        }
    }

Comment: @VaL Thnak you for your help!
After that I solved the problem: 
- replaced the mention deprecated class, add webdriver az execution parameter and I modified a small thing in accessing path of the story file.
Now everything is going fine! :) And thank you again.

Comment: @Val Hi again! I try to integrate the test into CI/CD pipeline and I have to convert the whole project to Maven.
I have som trouble with it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71601863/class-is-not-abstract-and-does-not-override-abstract-method-actionsbuilder-in

Do you have any suggestion what could be missing?