# Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionsBuilder() in org.openqa.selenium.HasInputDevices

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng, jbehave

I tried to migrate my Java project to Maven in IntelliJ as it should.
After it I tried to add dependencies to pom.xml
Right now the pom xml looks like this:

```
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>TravelLedger</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jbehave/jbehave-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jbehave.web/jbehave-web-selenium -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-web-selenium</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0b2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I get the following error message when I execute clean install:

```
travelledgerJbehave.webdriver.pages.LoginPagePOM is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionsBuilder() in org.openqa.selenium.HasInputDevices
```

The LoginPagePom class:

```java
public class LoginPagePOM extends AbstractPage {

    private WebDriverProvider driverProvider;

    public LoginPagePOM(WebDriverProvider driverProvider) {
        super(driverProvider);
        this.driverProvider = driverProvider;
    }

    public void open() {
        get("https://qa.abtlg.io");
        manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }}
```

The AbstractPage class:

```java
public abstract class AbstractPage extends WebDriverPage {

    public AbstractPage(WebDriverProvider driverProvider) {
        super(driverProvider);
    }

    public void found(String text) {
        found(getPageSource(), text);
    }

    public void found(String pageSource, String text) {
        if (!pageSource.contains(escapeHtml(text))) {
            fail("Text: '" + text + "' not found in page '" + pageSource + "'");
        }
    }

    public void found(List<String> texts) {
        for (String text : texts) {
            found(text);
        }
    }

    public void notFound(String text) {
        notFound(getPageSource(), text);
    }

    public void notFound(String pageSource, String text) {
        assertThat(pageSource.contains(escapeHtml(text)), is(false));
    }

    private String escapeHtml(String text) {
        return text.replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;");
    }}
```

What could be the solution?

Comment: might be because you are using 2.0b2 version of Selenium-Api.  If you need that package, update it to match your Selenium bindings.

Comment: @pcalkins thank you for the help!
I modified it to version 4.1.2 as selenium-java, selenium-firefox-driver and selenium-support are but I get another error.

In AbstractPage.java: cannot access org.openqa.selenium.HasInputDevice
Cannot find symbol come in AbstractPage.java in getPageSource() methods.

In the WebStories executor class I get: cannot access com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium error message.

I also get: cannot find symbol in LoginPagePOM in open() method at get("https://qa.abtlg.io") and at manage() method.

I also get cannot find symbol when I use findElement() method.

Comment: not familiar with your framework here, but seems like one of your dependencies isn't expecting Selenium 4.  Make sure everything is compatible.  Could also be duplicate classes... make sure you aren't duplicating any dependencies.

Comment: The framework based on JBehave and in another package I use TestNG.
I did not deleted the Java project Jar files from External libraries.
Could it be problem or could it make conflict?

Comment: you'd want to check namespaces... but looking at your code again, it might also be an architecture problem.  I'm not sure why an abstract class is extending another class... and the get and manage calls are a little odd.  Where is that method?  Follow up the chain... where is the driver injected?  Usually you'd have a webdriver object injected and do you do something like driver.get(), or driver.manage...  It seems to think you've extended the driver itself.

Comment: If I remember right, Selenium 4 comes with "-sources" files.  That's something to check for in your dependencies... they'll be for chromedriver, geckodriver, etc... you probably don't want those in your build.  (also in support methinks... also check to be sure Selenium-Java doesn't already include -support jars...)